# перенос программы с С++ Builder на Visual Studio? или другое?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, embarcadero

Есть старая программа на С++ Builder и желание перейти на Visual C++. Всегда считал, что аналогом нынешнего Embarcadero является проект С++ WinForm в VS. Однако в версии VS 2013 Community, с которой я начал пробовать, такого типа проектов нет (только WinForms для С# и VB).
   Что это означает? Что сейчас обычные windows-приложения на С++ таким путём уже не делают? А что тогда вместо этого позволяет создать форму и таскать на неё компоненты? Microsoft рекламирует WPF, но это опять не для С++, а только для С# и VB.
  Почитал ссылки на StackOverflow и выясняется, что народ в большинстве советует вообще использовать Qt.
  Итого: каков же сейчас "правильный" путь перевода старой программы С++ Builder на VS или другой софт?

Update:
причина, по которой хочется отказаться от С++ Builder - просто ненадёжность (последнее пёрышко - ошибка линкера LME288). Если бы не это - программа отличная.

Comment: Перепишите на Qt, собирайте студией...

Comment: По LME288 возможно поможет: http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-builder/thread1525701.html#post8044974

Comment: @alexolut Не поможет. Здесь больше вариантов http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28929516/c-builder-xe7-lme288-error, но, похоже, окончательного решения пока нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-простому `VCL` гуйню под `WPF/WinForms/Qt` Вы всё равно не переведете. Т.е. заимствовать дизайн конечно можно, но всё наполнение придется делать по-новой. Бизнес-логика должна перенестись без особых проблем, если мы говорим о сохранении языка *C++*, то есть без перехода на *C#* или ещё что. Т.о. если решение об отказе от *Embarcadero* окончательное, из всего обозначенного проще всего перейти на реализацию под *Qt*.

P.S. в общем и целом, данный вопрос, не совсем подходящий для StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4):

Если у вас старая программа на C++ builder, то она, наверное, еще и большая, и использует тонну компонент из VCL, которых нет ни в Visual C++ ни в QT ни в C#.

Возможность визуального редактирования формочек окон есть во многих средах разработки, однако VCL (Delphi и C++ Builder) безусловно является лидером по количестку визуальных компонент.

Если у вас возникло желание "перевести" вашу программу с одного языка на другой, то для начала нужно определиться с целью этого мероприятия. Цели могут быть разные:

1. Кроссплатформенность
2. Красота кода
3. Привлечение к работе программистов, специализирующихся на определённых языках и технологиях
4. Внешний вид приложения
5. Быстродействие и оптимизация
6. И многое другое.

У каждой среды и фреймворка есть свои плюсы и минусы. У VCL - огромное количество визуальных компонентов (многим из них нет аналогов в других фреймворках), в том числе для работы с базами данных, у C# - в том, что это C# - язык с самым большим количеством синтаксического сахара и очень проработанным фреймворком .net, QT - кроссплатформенность, и т.д.

---

*В любом случае, вам нужно быть готовым, что больш**у**ю или даже б**о**льшую часть кода вам придётся писать заново.*

---

Я бы не советовал вам начинать переводить большую программу на какую-либо другую платформу, предварительно не познакомившись с её плюсами и минусами.

Comment: Отказываться от VCL очень не хочется, но ошибку линкера LME288 стабильно преодолеть не удалось. Вкупе с кучей остальных недостатков пришлось решиться. Если не менять С++ на другой язык и ориентироваться только на Windows, то что вы имеете в виду под "многими средами разработки"?  Что, если не Qt?